# 0 confirmations after 3 days.

Tags: wallet

My transaction hasn't confirmed after 3 days , and I have no wallet for it to come back to, because I sent the money straight to the browser. If any miner can help me my code is below:
    1NGrDbtmQkMajCezPx7Mo9jjkQHSo1Xbdu

Comment: What does "I have no wallet" mean. You can't create BTC with a browser; some site or service must have transferred some of their coins to you. You need to contact them.

Answer (score 0):

There is no transaction showing for the wallet you have provided. Do you have txID by any chance or anymore information to check the transaction by?

In the past I have reasonable success with https://www.btcaccelerator.net/transaction-accelerator-viabtc ,but to be able to use it you would also need txID.

Also if transaction is not confirmed it will return to the wallet it was send from automatically, but it take quite a while (not sure exactly).